# Excel Add In development

Tags: c#, excel, office-2007, excel-addins

I want to develop Excel Add-In using which i want to read data from its different columns and send them to my database.

So can you suggest me good eBook or any website link which teaches the best add in development....???

Answer (score 2):

ExcelDna is a great framework for developing Excel Addins.  And its free.  http://exceldna.codeplex.com/

Comment: Greatly recommend!! Not only it's a great framework to use but also the author (Govert) is helping the community all the time. I used to develop Excel add-ins with VSTO and switching from it was such a relief!!

Answer (score 0):

This site provides help on the latest JavaScript Add-ins for Excel:
http://microsoft-office-add-ins.com

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting with one of the samples here: https://github.com/OfficeDev?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=excel

This sample, particularly, is helpful https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-VisualizeExcelData